# Hash-encode multiple columns containing "same" high-cardinality information in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, categorical-data, feature-selection

I have a dataset which includes numerical features and 25 very high cardinality categorical features, and I need to encode it in a meaningful way for it to be used for training predictive algorithms. My issue is that all 25 columns kind of correspond to the same concept, so ideally they should be all encoded as a group. Let me explain. The Pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
 memberid      code1   code2   code3 ...  code25      cost
 memberA       c1      c2      c4         c3          100.0
 memberB       c2      c3      c1         NaN         120.0
 memberC       c1      c2      c5         c3          200.0
```

This is generated by this code (only 4 "code" columns here):

```
data = {'memberid': ['memberA', 'memberB', 'memberC'], 
        'code1': ['c1', 'c2', 'c1'],
        'code2': ['c2', 'c3', 'c2'],
        'code3': ['c4', 'c1', 'c5'],
        'code25': ['c3', np.nan, 'c3'],
        'cost': [100.0, 120.0, 200.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['memberid', 'code1', 'code2', 'code3', 'code25', 'cost'])
```

I found a way to one-hot encode the "code" columns together, i.e., create a dataframe that looks like this:

```
has_c1   has_c2   has_c3   has_c4   has_c5      
1        1        1        1        0  
1        1        1        0        0
1        1        1        0        1
```

My problem is that all "code" columns take values of **very** high cardinality, so one-hot encoding like I just described would blow up the dimensions of my data by adding another ~15,000 (sparse) columns to the dataset. Unfortunately this is prohibitive from a memory standpoint for fitting ML algorithms, so I thought of looking into hashing encoding for this issue.

Unfortunately, although I was able to manually one-hot encode the "code" columns using numpy and ones/zeros, I don't know how I would be able to "group" the information of all "code" columns into, say, 50 columns including the components of hashing encoding. Is this doable? Or should I follow an entirely different approach on encoding these high cardinality "group" of features together?

Comment: have you tried `pd.get_dummies(... sparse=True)`?  I've never used this feature, but it would be the easiest solution if it works.

Comment: I will definitely look into it, because right now without a sparse designation the memory footprint of my dataset blows up to 20+ GB

Comment: post an update when you can, I'm interested in how this works for you

Answer (score 1):

Try with `get_dummies` then `sum`

```
output = pd.get_dummies(df.filter(like='code'), prefix='Has').sum(level=0,axis=1)
Out[549]: 
   Has_c1  Has_c2  Has_c3  Has_c4  Has_c5
0       1       1       1       1       0
1       1       1       1       0       0
2       1       1       1       0       1
```

Comment: can you say a bit about your solution?

Comment: @anon01 from what I understanding function here explain itself , doesn't it ?

Comment: This is straightforward, but I already have something like this in place (maybe I can try the `sparse=True` flag), but I would still end up with the 15k extra columns. Wondering if I can get an one-liner like this for a different type of encoding like hashing